# Converting GeoJSON object to shapely object

Tags: python, dataframe, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I have a geodataframe:

```
gdf
                              name  ...                                           geometry
0     INET_PL_273_EE_0_Seg_0_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[23.896...
1     INET_PL_273_EE_1_Seg_0_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[22.241...
2          INET_PL_357_Seg_0_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[13.592...
3          INET_PL_359_Seg_0_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[13.592...
4          INET_PL_361_Seg_0_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[13.592...
...                            ...  ...                                                ...
6318       EntsoG_Map__ST_25_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[13.887...
6319       EntsoG_Map__ST_26_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[23.080...
6320       EntsoG_Map__ST_26_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[6.7552...
6321      EntsoG_Map__ST_448_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[25.348...
6322      EntsoG_Map__ST_449_Seg_0  ...  {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [[25.348...
[6323 rows x 7 columns]
```

I created the geometry column via `gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.mapping(x))`. Now I want to convert it back.

Any simple hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shape()` function converts it back:

```
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.shape(x))
```